# How to run Batch Mode in FlinkSQL with kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, avro, flink-sql

I have record with create statement FLINK SQL.

```
CREATE TABLE en_trans (
  `transid` INTEGER,
  `productname` INTEGER,
   PRIMARY KEY (transid) NOT ENFORCED
) WITH (
  'connector' = 'upsert-kafka',
  'topic' = 'en_trans',
  'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '....:9092',
  'properties.group.id' = 'en_trans_group_test',
  'key.format' = 'avro-confluent',
  'value.format' = 'avro-confluent',
  'key.avro-confluent.url' = 'http://kafka-netlex-cp-schema-registry:8081',
  'value.avro-confluent.url' = 'http://kafka-netlex-cp-schema-registry:8081'
);
```

```
select * from en_trans where transid=123;
```

I got error

```
org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Querying an unbounded table 'default_catalog.default_database.en_trans' in batch mode is not allowed. The table source is unbounded.
```

I don't want stream mode, as i need provide this as a rest service, pagination purpose. NOT `STREAMING` mode.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to **streaming mode**, you need to create a `StreamTableEnvironment` instead of `BatchTableEnvironment`.

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
StreamTableEnvironment tEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env);
```

Then, register your table and run the query

```
tEnv.executeSql("CREATE TABLE en_trans (...) WITH (...)");
tEnv.sqlQuery("SELECT * FROM en_trans WHERE transid=123").execute().print();
```

Comment: No I don't want stream mode, i want Batch Mode to do pagination, run as a service.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73774980/3579818)

Basically just set the bound mode will do, but it's not working for `upsert-kafka`. My intention is to build a table as a service for users who can browse the data(kafkatopic) as service and pagination.

It turns up not working via `ksqldb` and `flinksql`